# Nested Divs backspace issue

Tags: html, css

I have an issue regarding nested divs. Both of the divs are editable.
The issue is if I write content in the div (i.e simple text) and then put my cursor on the start of inner(child) div and then press backspace it shifts the text in parent div.
Why is it happening? I know this is the default behavior.
And What could be the solution for this problem?

```
<head>
    <title>----</title>
</head>

<body style="100%">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

<div contenteditable="true" style="min-height:80%; min-width:100%; background-color:#00ffff">
    <div id="test" style="margin:auto; width:100%; background-color:#e3e3e3; 
border-width:5px; border-color:e9e9e9; word-wrap: break-word; overflow:hidden;  
min-height:25px;" contenteditable="true">

        Child Div Text here!!!

    </div>
                    Parent Div Text Here
</div>

</body>
```

regards,
Ahmed

Comment: You mean if you delete the amount of spaces in the child div, then the parent div moves correct?

Comment: I made a jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/3Zjvh/   When you are at the left edge of the child and hit backspace, the child div is deleted.

Comment: I see you're dilema. I've tried various ways of trying to stop the parent div text from merging into the child div text but with no success. Although I've seen it done. Not sure if these are any use to you... http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable and http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/rich-html-editing-in-the-browser-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

This may no be completely correct, but I think the reason that your `div`s are shifting is because of the way you set your width of the child `div`. If you do `width:100%` on the child `div` then the size of that `div` will stretch to include all of the spacing. You have also not specified any position attributes, so the parent `div` will put itself right next to the child `div`. This means that any changes to the child `div`s position and width (which will change with the number of `' '`s you have) will also change the parent `div`s position. If you do not want the parent `div` to move, then you need to either A) Specify a set `width` for the child `div` or, B) Set a position for each `div`. If you had a `css` file it would look something like this:

A)

```
/* You would need to add IDs to each div so I am just going to do child */
#child
{
   width: 200px; /* Set number */
}
```

**OR**

B)

```
#child
{
    position: absolute /* Or however you wish to do this */
    top: 10px; /* Some number */
    left: 10px; /* Again whatever number */
}
```